# Spring Bean Configuration xml file does load load in IteliJ Idea

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to load a spring bean conflagration file from classpath in InteliJ. But It does not load. It show an exception.
[image: InteliJ screen shot]

```
Connected to server
[2016-12-13 09:58:50,515] Artifact eeducation:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
13-Dec-2016 21:58:54.181 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
13-Dec-2016 21:58:54.290 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
13-Dec-2016 21:58:54.611 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.prepareRefresh Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Tue Dec 13 21:58:54 ALMT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
13-Dec-2016 21:58:54.721 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [com/habibur/app/config/dao-config.xml]
13-Dec-2016 21:58:54.721 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext Context initialization failed
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [com/habibur/app/config/dao-config.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [com/habibur/app/config/dao-config.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:344)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
    at
```

Comment: Judging from the structure you are using maven, maven requires that non java sources be under `src/main/resources` not `src/main/java` in that location it will be ignored. It has nothing to do with Intellij but that is how maven works.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't this configuration file should be under your resources folder?

Comment: I am new in IntelliJ Idea. I am conformable in eclipse. In Eclipse I created the same file in a java package. Missilery I have done here. What should I have to load the bean file in IntelliJ?

Comment: Can you not move it under WEB-INF and reference it with:

Comment: <param-value>/WEB-INF/dao-config.xml</param-value>